# What is the difference between two words "amorphous" and "mercurial"?

Tags: meaning

The meanings in the dictionary are as follows:
amorphous:
without a clearly defined shape or form.

mercurial:
subject to sudden or unpredictable changes of mood or mind.

What is the origin of the word "mercurial"? If the chemical element mercury is it's origin, then since mercury is amorphous, should both of these words not mean the same?

Comment: Mercury has several other properties too. That doesn't mean that the names for all those properties mean the same.

Comment: Dictionary definitions should make it obvious that *amorphous* and *mercurial* are two completely distinct concepts, so that (and the origins of both) are General Reference. As to "should both of these words not mean the same", mercury is also both ***metallic*** and ***liquid*** - but no-one would suppose those two words therefore ought to "mean the same".

Comment: I always thought _mercurial_ was from the Roman god Mercury not the element (or the planet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merely speculating:
Mercurial must have evolved from the property that mercury is volatile, i.e., it can expand and contract quickly. It has nothing to do with its amorphous property.

Consider this example:
My plans for visiting France are amorphous (shapeless).
My plans for visiting France have been mercurial (not constant/changing very fast).

Notice the subtle difference. The first sentence tilts towards saying that I did little/no planning while the second sentence suggests rapid change of plans

Comment: It's not appropriate to use the word 'volatile' with any other senses than 'prone to evaporate', 'prone to dissociate', and 'prone to explode' for a substance.

Comment: Why speculate? Why not work at it?